# Combining rows based on same coordinates but need to do different functions for each column

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to combine rows with the same coordinates, but with multiple columns that require different rules when combining. I have no idea where to start. The data looks something like

```
 X        Y     up   low     1       2     3    acc
3500   160000   2     6     4.4     4.4    na   aaac
3500   160000   6     11     na     3.0    1.0  aaac
4500   120434   0     9      2.2    2.2    na   abab
32999  342359   5     8      na     6.0    na   aaca
32999  342359   8     15     na     4.0    4.0  aaca
```

For any rows that have the same x and y coordinates, I want the rows to be combined where 'up' takes the lowest value between the two rows, 'low' the highest, for 1/2/3 if there is only 1 value then use that but if there are more then take the average.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `dplyr`

```
df[df=='na']=NA
df%>%group_by(X,Y)%>%summarise(up=min(up,na.rm=T),low=max(low,na.rm=T),X1=mean(X1,na.rm=T),X2=mean(X2,na.rm=T),X3=mean(X3,na.rm=T),acc=unique(acc))
    # A tibble: 3 x 8
# Groups:   X [?]
      X      Y    up   low    X1    X2    X3   acc
  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1  3500 160000     2    11    NA   3.7    NA  aaac
2  4500 120434     0     9    NA   2.2    NA  abab
3 32999 342359     5    15    NA   5.0    NA  aaca
```